# What is the answer of $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{(n-1)}\cdot n}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I found a limit question in my textbook but i could not obtained the result given by answer key.

Let me introduce the question :  $ \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{(n-1)}\cdot n}{(n+1)!}$

I tried to separate it into two part such that $ \lim_{n\to \infty}{(-1)}^{(n-1)}\cdot\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$

As you see, this partition gave me "$\text{oscillating (undetermined)}$".$0$

However, the answer is zero. What am I missing? Thank you for your helps ...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe i corrected it

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(-1)}^{(n-1)}.\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$ has no sense, since $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(-1)}^{(n-1)}$ does not exist (so you are not *allowed* to write it).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yeah , i know it and i said that it is undefined but the book say that answer is zero .Moreover wolfram alpha corroborated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule that $\lim_n (a_n b_n) = \left( \lim_n a_n\right)\left(\lim_n b_n\right)$ is valid **only** when both of the latter limits exist, meaning both are actual finite numbers (not $\pm\infty$ and not something that oscillates). And $(-1)^n$ oscillates.

But the limit you started with exists.
$$
\frac{-n}{(n+1)!} \le \frac{(-1)^n \cdot n}{(n+1)!} \le \frac n {(n+1)!}
$$
Now observe that
$$
\frac n {(n+1)!} = \frac n {n+1} \cdot \frac 1 {n!}.
$$
And this one you **can** partition, finding limits of the two factors separately. The first one approaches $1$ and the second approaches $0.$ Thus the sequence whose limit you seek is squeezed between two sequences whose limit is $0.$

Comment: It's $(n+1)!$ at the denominator

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over(n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n-1)!}=0\Longrightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}n\over(n+1)!}=0 $

Comment: In contrast with proof via sqeeze theorem, demonstrated by SweetPotato, I think ιt's not a strict mathematical proof.

Comment: This is fine. If ${a_n\rightarrow 0}$ then we can prove ${(-1)^{n-1}a_n\rightarrow 0}$. Since by definition ${\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists\ N_0}$ such that ${\forall\ n>N_0}$ we have ${\left|(-1)^{n-1}a_n\right|=|a_n| < \epsilon}$, and so by definition ${(-1)^{n-1}a_n\rightarrow 0}$

Answer (score 0):

Try squeeze.

$0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-n}{(n+1)!} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{(n+1)!} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{(n+1)!} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You managed to rewrite your sequence as $x_n=y_n\cdot z_n$ where $y_n$ is bounded and $z_n\to0$. (In your case, $y_n=(-1)^n$ and $z_n=n/(n+1)!$.

In general, the following is true: If $y_n$ is bounded and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} z_n=0$ then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_nz_n=0.$$

*Proof.* Let $M$ be such that $|y_n|\le M$ for each $n$. If we are given $\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}\ve>0$, then there is $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$ we have
$$|z_n| < \frac\ve{M}.$$
Then for every $n\ge n_0$ we also get
$$|y_nz_n| < M\cdot \frac\ve{M} = \ve.$$
This shows that the sequence $(y_nz_n)$ converges to zero. $\square$